# D3 directed graph editor - v5 to v6 migration issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found this http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347 graph from bl.ocks.org and want to migrate to D3 v6.

I managed to get running without any syntax errors but the result seems wrong if you click on a node.

I guess the function:

```
function mousedown(event) {
        // because :active only works in WebKit?
        svg.classed('active', true);

        if (event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

        // insert new node at point
        const point = d3.pointer(this);
        const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
        nodes.push(node);

        restart();
    }
```

Triggers the unwanted behavior. As soon as I changed `d3.mouse(this)` to `d3.pointer(this)` the origin node starts to dance erratically.

Any hint to fix my current code below ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 dyn link</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    svg {
        background-color: #FFF;
        cursor: default;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
        cursor: crosshair;
    }

    path.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 4px;
        cursor: default;
    }

    svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    path.link.selected {
        stroke-dasharray: 10, 2;
    }

    path.link.dragline {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    path.link.hidden {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }

    circle.node {
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    circle.node.reflexive {
        stroke: #000 !important;
        stroke-width: 2.5px;
    }

    text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    text.id {
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        // set up SVG for D3
        const width = window.innerWidth
        const height = window.innerHeight
        const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        const svg = d3.select('body')
            .append('svg')
            .on('contextmenu', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); })
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);

        // set up initial nodes and links
        //  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
        //  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black circle).
        //  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.
        const nodes = [
            { id: 0, reflexive: false },
            { id: 1, reflexive: true },
            { id: 2, reflexive: false }
        ];
        let lastNodeId = 2;
        const links = [
            { source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true },
            { source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true }
        ];

        // init D3 force layout
        const force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
            .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
            .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
            .on('tick', tick);

        // init D3 drag support
        const drag = d3.drag()
            // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
            .filter((event) => event.button === 0 || event.button === 2)
            .on('start', (event, d) => {
                if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();

                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            })
            .on('drag', (event, d) => {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            })
            .on('end', (event, d) => {
                if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);

                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            });

        // define arrow markers for graph links
        svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', 6)
            .attr('markerWidth', 3)
            .attr('markerHeight', 3)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#000');

        svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
            .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
            .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
            .attr('refX', 4)
            .attr('markerWidth', 3)
            .attr('markerHeight', 3)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
            .attr('fill', '#000');

        // line displayed when dragging new nodes
        const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
            .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
            .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');

        // handles to link and node element groups
        let path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
        let circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

        // mouse event vars
        let selectedNode = null;
        let selectedLink = null;
        let mousedownLink = null;
        let mousedownNode = null;
        let mouseupNode = null;

        function resetMouseVars() {
            mousedownNode = null;
            mouseupNode = null;
            mousedownLink = null;
        }

        // update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
        function tick() {
            // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
            path.attr('d', (d) => {
                const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
                const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
                const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
                const normX = deltaX / dist;
                const normY = deltaY / dist;
                const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
                const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
                const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
                const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
                const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
                const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

                return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
            });

            circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
        }

        // update graph (called when needed)
        function restart() {
            // path (link) group
            path = path.data(links);

            // update existing links
            path.classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
                .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
                .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '');

            // remove old links
            path.exit().remove();

            // add new links
            path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
                .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
                .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '')
                .on('mousedown', (d) => {
                    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

                    // select link
                    mousedownLink = d;
                    selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
                    selectedNode = null;
                    restart();
                })
                .merge(path);

            // circle (node) group
            // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
            circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

            // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
            circle.selectAll('circle')
                .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
                .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

            // remove old nodes
            circle.exit().remove();

            // add new nodes
            const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

            g.append('svg:circle')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('r', 12)
                .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
                .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
                .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)
                .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                    if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
                    // enlarge target node
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
                })
                .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                    if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
                    // unenlarge target node
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
                })
                .on('mousedown', (event, d) => {
                    if (event.ctrlKey) return;

                    // select node
                    mousedownNode = d;
                    selectedNode = (mousedownNode === selectedNode) ? null : mousedownNode;
                    selectedLink = null;

                    // reposition drag line
                    dragLine
                        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
                        .classed('hidden', false)
                        .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}`);

                    restart();
                })
                .on('mouseup', function (d) {
                    if (!mousedownNode) return;

                    // needed by FF
                    dragLine
                        .classed('hidden', true)
                        .style('marker-end', '');

                    // check for drag-to-self
                    mouseupNode = d;
                    if (mouseupNode === mousedownNode) {
                        resetMouseVars();
                        return;
                    }

                    // unenlarge target node
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

                    // add link to graph (update if exists)
                    // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
                    const isRight = mousedownNode.id < mouseupNode.id;
                    const source = isRight ? mousedownNode : mouseupNode;
                    const target = isRight ? mouseupNode : mousedownNode;

                    const link = links.filter((l) => l.source === source && l.target === target)[0];
                    if (link) {
                        link[isRight ? 'right' : 'left'] = true;
                    } else {
                        links.push({ source, target, left: !isRight, right: isRight });
                    }

                    // select new link
                    selectedLink = link;
                    selectedNode = null;
                    restart();
                });

            // show node IDs
            g.append('svg:text')
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 4)
                .attr('class', 'id')
                .text((d) => d.id);

            circle = g.merge(circle);

            // set the graph in motion
            force
                .nodes(nodes)
                .force('link').links(links);

            force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        }

        function mousedown(event) {
            // because :active only works in WebKit?
            svg.classed('active', true);

            if (event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

            // insert new node at point
            const point = d3.pointer(this);
            const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
            nodes.push(node);

            restart();
        }

        function mousemove() {
            if (!mousedownNode) return;

            // update drag line
            dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${d3.pointer(this)[0]},${d3.pointer(this)[1]}`);
        }

        function mouseup() {
            if (mousedownNode) {
                // hide drag line
                dragLine
                    .classed('hidden', true)
                    .style('marker-end', '');
            }

            // because :active only works in WebKit?
            svg.classed('active', false);

            // clear mouse event vars
            resetMouseVars();
        }

      
      
        // app starts here
        svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
            .on('mousemove', mousemove)
            .on('mouseup', mouseup);
        restart();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track:

- Everywhere there's a reference to `d3.event` have that function take `event` as an argument and then reference `event` in the logic (i.e. lose the `d3.`). This applies to all the `drag`, `mousedown`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseup`, `keydown` and `keyup` handlers.
- `d3.mouse` becomes `d3.pointer` except in...
- In the `mousemove` function use `event.x` and `event.y` instead of `d3.mouse(this)[0]` and `d3.mouse(this)[1]`.

In the example below, I use:

```
dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${event.x},${event.y}`);
```

Admittedly, this seems to be at odds with the [v6 release notes](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#pointer) to use `d3.pointer(event)` instead of `d3.mouse(this)` but `event` has the `x` and `y` properties you need.

Consider:

```
const p = d3.pointer(event);
dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${p.x},${p.y}`);
```

This didn't work for me in terms of getting a `dragLine` I can manipulate and see, prior to attaching to the target node.

Example port from v5 to v6:

```js
// set up SVG for D3
const width = 600;
const height = 180;
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .on('contextmenu', () => { d3.event.preventDefault(); })
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

// set up initial nodes and links
//  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
//  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black circle).
//  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.
const nodes = [
  { id: 0, reflexive: false },
  { id: 1, reflexive: true },
  { id: 2, reflexive: false }
];
let lastNodeId = 2;
const links = [
  { source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true },
  { source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true }
];

// init D3 force layout
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .on('tick', tick);

// init D3 drag support
const drag = d3.drag(event)
  // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
  .filter(() => event.button === 0 || event.button === 2)
  .on('start', (event, d) => {
    if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();

    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  })
  .on('drag', (event, d) => {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
  })
  .on('end', (event, d) => {
    if (!event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);

    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  });

// define arrow markers for graph links
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 6)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 4)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

// line displayed when dragging new nodes
const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
  .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');

// handles to link and node element groups
let path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
let circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

// mouse event vars
let selectedNode = null;
let selectedLink = null;
let mousedownLink = null;
let mousedownNode = null;
let mouseupNode = null;

function resetMouseVars() {
  mousedownNode = null;
  mouseupNode = null;
  mousedownLink = null;
}

// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
  // path (link) group
  path = path.data(links);

  // update existing links
  path.classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '');

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '')
    .on('mousedown', (event, d) => {
      if (event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedownLink = d;
      selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    })
    .merge(path);

  // circle (node) group
  // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
  circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
  circle.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

  // remove old nodes
  circle.exit().remove();

  // add new nodes
  const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

  g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 12)
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)
    .on('mouseover', function (event, d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // enlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (event, d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
    })
    .on('mousedown', (event, d) => {
      if (event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select node
      mousedownNode = d;
      selectedNode = (mousedownNode === selectedNode) ? null : mousedownNode;
      selectedLink = null;

      // reposition drag line
      dragLine
        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed('hidden', false)
        .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}`);

      restart();
    })
    .on('mouseup', function (event, d) {
      if (!mousedownNode) return;

      // needed by FF
      dragLine
        .classed('hidden', true)
        .style('marker-end', '');

      // check for drag-to-self
      mouseupNode = d;
      if (mouseupNode === mousedownNode) {
        resetMouseVars();
        return;
      }

      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

      // add link to graph (update if exists)
      // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
      const isRight = mousedownNode.id < mouseupNode.id;
      const source = isRight ? mousedownNode : mouseupNode;
      const target = isRight ? mouseupNode : mousedownNode;

      const link = links.filter((l) => l.source === source && l.target === target)[0];
      if (link) {
        link[isRight ? 'right' : 'left'] = true;
      } else {
        links.push({ source, target, left: !isRight, right: isRight });
      }

      // select new link
      selectedLink = link;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    });

  // show node IDs
  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id')
    .text((d) => d.id);

  circle = g.merge(circle);

  // set the graph in motion
  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force('link').links(links);

  force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}

function mousedown(event) {
  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', true);

  if (event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

  // insert new node at point
  const point = d3.pointer(this);
  const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
  nodes.push(node);

  restart();
}

function mousemove(event) {
  if (!mousedownNode) return;

  // update drag line
  dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${event.x},${event.y}`);
}

function mouseup(event) {
  if (mousedownNode) {
    // hide drag line
    dragLine
      .classed('hidden', true)
      .style('marker-end', '');
  }

  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', false);

  // clear mouse event vars
  resetMouseVars();
}

function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
  const toSplice = links.filter((l) => l.source === node || l.target === node);
  for (const l of toSplice) {
    links.splice(links.indexOf(l), 1);
  }
}

// only respond once per keydown
let lastKeyDown = -1;

function keydown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (lastKeyDown !== -1) return;
  lastKeyDown = event.keyCode;

  // ctrl
  if (event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.call(drag);
    svg.classed('ctrl', true);
    return;
  }

  if (!selectedNode && !selectedLink) return;

  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 46: // delete
      if (selectedNode) {
        nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
        spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        links.splice(links.indexOf(selectedLink), 1);
      }
      selectedLink = null;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
      break;
    case 66: // B
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to both left and right
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 76: // L
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to left only
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = false;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 82: // R
      if (selectedNode) {
        // toggle node reflexivity
        selectedNode.reflexive = !selectedNode.reflexive;
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to right only
        selectedLink.left = false;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
  }
}

function keyup(event) {
  lastKeyDown = -1;

  // ctrl
  if (event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.on('.drag', null);
    svg.classed('ctrl', false);
  }
}

// app starts here
svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove)
  .on('mouseup', mouseup);
d3.select(window)
  .on('keydown', keydown)
  .on('keyup', keyup);
restart();
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

path.link.selected {
  stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
}

path.link.dragline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
  stroke: #000 !important;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.id {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- 
Copyright (c) 2013 Ross Kirsling

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. 
-->
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Robin, there is only one bug. The new nodes aren´t created at the mouse position. They appear almost at the same position again and again, which also explains the second issue that the dragLine isn´t exactly at the mouse position too.

Comment: It was necessary to change point.x and point.y to point[0] and point[1]. For mousedown and mousemove. Now the new nodes are created at the correct position and the dragLine fixed. Cheers Robin, you helped me a lot.